# Foundation - Prevent dropdown from closing when clicking a select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using the foundation dropdown that comes out of the box and I have a select tag so a user can choose a language.

But when a user clicks on the select tag foundations dropdown menu closes not allowing them to pick a language.

so ideally I'd like them to be able to select a country and language then when they click on the button to then close the menu and obviously this will cause a refresh of the page.

I've looked into using the aria-autoclose attr in the documentation but I can't get my head round how or where to use it.

```
  <li>
  <a href="">
      UK
      <i class="icon-arrow_down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="menu country-selector">
      <li class="country-selector__item">
        <h6 class="country-selector__heading">Your Country</h6>
        <select name="" id="" aria-autoclose="false">
            <option value="">Germany</option>
            <option value="">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="">France</option>
            <option value="">Spain</option>
            <option value="">Belgium</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li class="country-selector__item">
        <h6 class="country-selector__heading">Your Language</h6>
        <select name="" id="" aria-autoclose="false">
            <option value="">German</option>
            <option value="">English</option>
            <option value="">Italiano</option>
            <option value="">Dansk</option>
            <option value="">Norsk</option>
        </select>            
      </li>
      <li class="country-selector__item">
        <button type="submit" class="small expanded button" aria-autoclose="true">CHANGE</button>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Let me know if I need to explain anything in a better way.

Comment: May be [this link](https://www.bootply.com/116350) will help you

Comment: Thanks yash. but I'm using foundation not bootstrap.

Comment: But actually it does help me.

Comment: can you elaborate on the problem

https://codepen.io/stephendesjardins/pen/wqREQZ

I made this codepen and I can't figure out what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
* Language Select Tag
*/
$('.country-selector select').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

I just needed to stop the event from bubbling on the element that I wanted to not close for anyone else wondering how to do this